# SQL Server : cannot connect via ODBC driver

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker, odbc

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server database on Azure through an ODBC driver using Docker. I follow the official doc from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017#ubuntu-1604-1) but getting the error:

> Error: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2' : file not found
>    errors:
>   message: '[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can\'t open lib \'/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2\' : file not found', state: '01000'
>   error: '[node-odbc] SQL_ERROR'
>   '[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can\'t open lib \'/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2\' : file not found', state: '01000'

When I check if the driver is installed using `odbcinst -j`, I get:

```
unixODBC 2.3.7
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /root/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

In `odbcinst.ini` I have:

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.2
UsageCount=1
```

Any hint what I might miss? Locally on my Mac I can connect to the DB and do a query but cannot using the Docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list

RUN apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get install -y make
RUN apt-get install -y apt-transport-https
RUN apt-get update && ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql unixodbc unixodbc-dev 
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bash_profile
RUN echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/opt/mssql-tools/bin"' >> ~/.bashrc
# RUN source ~/.bashrc
RUN apt-get install -y unixodbc-dev
ADD . /var/www/app
WORKDIR /var/www/app
RUN npm install && \
    npm cache clean --force
RUN npm run build 
EXPOSE 3000:80
```

Comment: Any news on this topic. Are you sure about the path of the driver?

Comment: Any update on this? I also have the same problem.

Comment: I am facing the same problem. It works outside container. but within container, it failed.